# SQL Server : Count of XML Elements By Element Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have successfully obtained a count of sub elements using this query.

```
SELECT  
    raa.ApplicationXML.value('count(Root/ThirdParty/*)', 'Int') as [Bureau Count]
FROM 
    Table1 raa
```

However, I want to group this count by the actual name of the sub element.

My XML looks something like this:

Record 1:

```
<Root>
    <ThirdParty>
        <BureauRed />
        <BureauGreen />
        <BureauBlue />
    </ThirdParty>
</Root>
```

Record 2:

```
<Root>
    <ThirdParty>
        <BureauRed />
        <BureauPurple />
        <BureauBlue />
    </ThirdParty>
</Root>
```

Record 3:

```
<Root>
    <ThirdParty>
        <BureauGreen />
        <BureauRed />
        <BureauPurple />
        <BureauOrange />
        <BureauBlue />
    </ThirdParty>
</Root>
```

Not only do I need to pull the count of each bureau, but I need to get the name of the bureau (BureauRed, BureauGreen, BureauBlue, etc.) When I try to group by count I get the error:

> XML methods are not allowed in a GROUP BY clause.

Using this query:

```
SELECT  
    raa.ApplicationXML.value('count(Root/ThirdParty/*)', 'Int') as [Bureau Count]
FROM 
    Table1 raa
GROUP BY
    raa.ApplicationXML.value('count(Root/ThirdParty/*)', 'Int')
```

How do I get the count and the name of the bureau?

I'm looking for this result:

```
Bureau         Count
============   =====
BureauRed      3
BureauGreen    2
BureauBlue     3
BureauPurple   2
BureauOrange   1
```

Comment: Provide expected result for those three records

Comment: It's better to give us sample data as filled temp table

Comment: I updated the story; sorry the numbers didn't line up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group after recieving data via XQuery:

```
DECLARE @xml1 xml = 
'<Root>
    <ThirdParty>
        <BureauRed />
        <BureauGreen />
        <BureauBlue />
    </ThirdParty>
</Root>';
DECLARE @xml2 xml = 
'<Root>
    <ThirdParty>
        <BureauRed />
        <BureauPurple />
        <BureauBlue />
    </ThirdParty>
</Root>';
DECLARE @xml3 xml = 
'<Root>
    <ThirdParty>
        <BureauGreen />
        <BureauRed />
        <BureauPurple />
        <BureauOrange />
        <BureauBlue />
    </ThirdParty>
</Root>';

DECLARE @temp TABLE (XmlData xml);

INSERT @temp VALUES (@xml1), (@xml2), (@xml3);

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT n.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)') nodeName
        FROM @temp t
        CROSS APPLY t.XmlData.nodes('/Root/ThirdParty/*') x(n)
)
SELECT nodeName, count(*) cnt
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY nodeName;
```

Output:

```
nodeName                                           cnt
-------------------------------------------------- -----------
BureauBlue                                         3
BureauGreen                                        2
BureauOrange                                       1
BureauPurple                                       2
BureauRed                                          3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the elements that are children of `Root/ThirdParty` first and use that derived table to do the counting.

```sql
DECLARE @tv TABLE(x XML);

INSERT INTO @tv(x)VALUES(
N'<Root>
    <ThirdParty>
        <BureauRed />
        <BureauGreen />
        <BureauBlue />
    </ThirdParty>
</Root>'),(
N'<Root>
    <ThirdParty>
        <BureauRed />
        <BureauPurple />
        <BureauBlue />
    </ThirdParty>
</Root>'),(
N'<Root>
    <ThirdParty>
        <BureauGreen />
        <BureauRed />
        <BureauPurple />
        <BureauOrange />
        <BureauBlue />
    </ThirdParty>
</Root>');

WITH bureaus AS (
    SELECT 
        bureau=n.v.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(256)')
    FROM
        @tv
        CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/Root/ThirdParty/*') AS n(v)
)
SELECT
    bureau,
    [count]=COUNT(*)
FROM
    bureaus
GROUP BY
    bureau
ORDER BY
    bureau;
```